# django-allauth not saving google extra data

Tags: python, django, google-oauth, django-allauth

here how my `settings.py` is

```
# other settings

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'email',
            'public_profile',
            'user_friends',
            'user_gender',
            'user_birthday',
            'user_location',
            'user_link',
            'user_age_range',
        ],
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'middle_name',
            'name',
            'short_name',
            'name_format',
            'gender',
            'birthday',
            'age_range',
            'friends',
            'location',
            'picture',
            'link',
        ],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
        'VERSION': 'v7.0',
    },
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.emails.read',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.agerange.read',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'online',
        }
    }
}
```

it's working fine with **facebook** and i get what i want there, but with **google** everything works will while signing (asks for permissions.. everything goes will) it authenticates the user and save it on db, but on **extra data** field i just get

```
{
  "id": "...",
  "email": "...",
  "verified_email": true,
  "name": "..",
  "given_name": "..",
  "picture": "..",
  "locale": "en"
}
```

so what happens to **birthday**, **gender**, **addresses**, **agerange** and other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data protected Fields such as *birthday, gender, addresses, agerange* are generally set to **Private** by default. Therefore, External API access is restricted to just **Public** fields for that given user.

For example, for birthday:

If you access your own account's [birthday](http://myaccount.google.com/birthday). You'll notice it may be set to **'Only Me'** indicating it's set to Private.

In order to access all the fields you're restricted from accessing you must change this profile configuration for all components making them **Public**.